# Git, Ubuntu. Сравнение файлов

Tags: ubuntu, git, github

Есть приложение под Git для Ubuntu что бы делать сравнения файлов, максимально похожее на compare в GitHub? Удобней и проще средства я пока еще не видел. Хотелось бы пользоваться вместо стандартного diff

Comment: смотрю на [пример этого самого compare](https://github.com/github/linguist/compare/master...maintainers) и не понимаю, в чём тут отличие от того, что выдаёт `diff -ruaN file1 file2` (`git diff` по умолчанию вызывает `diff` с такими же опциями).

Answer (score 3):

попробуйте установить утилиту meld. Она есть в стандартном репозитории. Она умеет сравнивать два или три файла между собой, а также умеет работать с git/svn и другими системами контроля версий. Для этого просто запустите ее в каталоге с исходниками вот так `meld .`.

так же рекомендую посмотреть на gitg и giggle. Они немного отличаются, но иногда очень удобны. (они напрямую файлы не сравнивают, но коммиты умеют показывать красиво)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно для вашей задачи подойдет GUI для гит напрмер:

- GitEye - http://www.collab.net/downloads/giteye
- gitg - https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gitg/

И еще тут можете посмотреть: https://git-scm.com/download/gui/linux

Comment: @metalurgus, является. Использовать git для получения того же, что делает git - ну логично же.